# Why do preprocessor commands have to start as first nonwhite space

Tags: c++, visual-studio, c-preprocessor

I am trying to do a #ifndef part way through a setter line and I received this error

> "Error 20  error C2014: preprocessor command must start as first nonwhite space"

I am aware of the error means, I am just curious of why it is like that? Is it a compiler choice? What is the reasoning behind this? That it is easier for the user to notice?

Here is the code if someone is wondering:

```
inline void SetSomething(int value) { #ifndef XBOX ASSERT(value <= 1); #endif test = value; };
```

Comment: Can you show the code that triggered this error?

Comment: Sure I added it, I am not sure there is a way around it though.

Comment: I suppose it comes down from '70s when C preprocessor took form... And got fixed in standards in the '80s. Why, not sure.

Comment: Well, for things like `#define` how would the preprocessor know when the `#define` substitution should end if not with a newline?

Comment: The way around it is to add newlines to your code. An `inline` function definition doesn't have to be on a single line.

Comment: #cdhowie at the endif?

Comment: #Keith Thompson but then I would need to duplicate my code twice.

Comment: @marsh How is it to know that you don't want `#endif` as part of the substitution?

Comment: Well for #define it makes sense, not sure about all preprocessor commands.

Comment: The whole C/C++ preprocessor is evil in multiple ways, anyway. Use it C++ as little as you can, in idiomatic ways only. Prefer templates in C++ for many things you'd use preprocessor in C.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At first C did not have any standard preprocessor. Then people started using preprocessing as an external tool. You might note that the `#` is the same as with comments in general in Unix-land shell scripts.

As the language evolved the preprocessor became integrated with the compiler and more part of the language proper, but it kept its totally different structure, namely, in particular that it's line oriented while the C and C++ core languages are free form.

After that the lines have blurred a bit more. Now the preprocessing typically adds `#line` directives or the equivalent for use by the core language compiler, also `#pragma` directives are for the core language compiler, and in the other direction we now have `_Pragma` (IIRC). Still the structure is mostly as it was originally. C and C++ are evolved languages, not designed languages.

Comment: I don't think `_Pragma` is actually a preprocessor thing, so it's not in the "other direction". That other direction isn't really convenient anyway because of the phases of compilation.

Comment: @MSalters: The purpose of `_Pragma` is to be usable in macros (because you can't have preprocessor direectives such as `#pragma` in a macro). So it's in the other direction, part of the core language supporting the preprocessor. As opposed to `#pragma`, which is part of the preprocessor supporting the core language.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf: But `_Pragma` isn't supporting the preprocessor. In fact, it has nothing to do with it. `#pragma` also isn't really a preprocessor directive --- it just happens to have a syntax that looks *as if* it's one (if it was, how could it influence things like alignment?).

Comment: @TimČas: The Holy C++ Standard lists `#pragma` as a preprocessor directive. In C++98, C++03, C++11 and C++14 (all standards so far) it's §16.6, named "Pragma directive", in section 16 which is named "Preprocessing directives". Let's agree that the standard is right about the formal terminology. That done, we can agree that `#pragma` can't be fully processed by a separate pure textual preprocessing. Which was much of my point.

Answer (score 2):

Taking a look into the standard (section 16 "Preprocessing Directives") starting with # as the frirst non whitespace character *is* what makes a preprocessing directive by definition.

> A preprocessing directive consists of a sequence of preprocessing tokens that satisfies the following constraints:
>   The first token in the sequence is a # preprocessing token that (at the start of translation phase 4) is either
>   the first character in the source file (optionally after white space containing no new-line characters) or that
>   follows white space containing at least one new-line character.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the most important reason, it's because the standard says so.

If you want to know why the standard says so, it's the easiest way to get the neccessary functionality.
Remember that preprocessing and compiling are two potentially completely separate tasks, and the preprocessor has no idea at all about the language of its output.